# How to place TYPO3 frontend output in anywhere

Tags: typo3

I am new to TYPO3 and creating a TYPO3 extension. Extension can be added to a given place by the BE using the wizard. No problem.

My question is how can I add/call extension manually any place I want. For example among text.

What i mean is like Joomlas Mambots. Call the extension inside `{myextentionName}` among text for example.

Please any idea/help with an example is kindly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typoscript tree and plugin keyword with the extension name for example plugin.xxxx.pi1.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `TypoScript` definition for each plugin below `tt_content.list.20.<plugin-key>`.
On top of that, most plugins provide a fully working version below `plugin.<ext-key>`.

If all fails, you can use the `USER` object to call the plugin directly. You will find an example in one of the above paths, because that is what the plugins to after all.

Comment: I went through typo script and found that something call markers. Is that what u all talking about that I can use inside template or content element. any example please. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: No. You will need to read the docs to understand what I wrote. I have no time to write a documentation of TYPO3 CMS here. You need to sort out the basic concepts and then I can help you with the details. You can find all relevant documentation at http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/.
If you want to include your plugin inside some textfield (e.g. ``tt_content`` > ``bodytext``), then you can use the stdWrap function ``replacement`` to archive that, next to the old marker based approach. You will need some advanced ``TypoScript`` magic for this either way.