# Insert the FE plugin using TypoScript

Tags: typo3

Hi I'm new to Typo3 and developing an extension to generate some list using Extbase and Fluid. I can Install the extension to what ever the column available in the BE and view the result in front end. Now what i want is to render the list inside some content among text.

Ex: - Some texts on the content element and {myExtention.myList} and the rest of the text.

So that i can plug to any place in the web page the extension to see my list.

Is there any way to do this in Typo3 extension. If there is please provide me some example or a like that explain the way to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place TYPO3 frontend output in anywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601405/how-to-place-typo3-frontend-output-in-anywhere)

Comment: @Phpdna the questions are differen

Answer (score 0):

Use TypoScript cObject functions `USER` or `USER_INT` (for non-cached) see:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html

> This calls either a PHP function or a method in a class. This is very useful if you want to incorporate your own data processing or content.

This example shows how you can load/insert a Extbase action by TypoScript:

```
lib.something = USER_INT
lib.something {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = TYPO3
    pluginName = Pi1
    extensionName = ExtensionName
    controller = ControllerName
    switchableControllerActions {
        ControllerName {
            1 = actionName
        }
    }
    settings =< plugin.tx_extensionname.settings
    persistence =< plugin.tx_extensionname.persistence
    view =< plugin.tx_extensionname.view
}
```

Comment: This isn't meant for plugins and it was mentioned in the other question.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand it yet. If I want to let the user to configure the extension out put to a place where ever in the page he/she wants then how that is gonna be done?  If there is an example tutorial with this kind of problems please give me the link or a kind of explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thats basicly the whole purpose of writing a plugin that renders something (e.g. a list of your records). You insert it as a plugin in the backend on any page you'd like your list to be shown and put whatever content you like before and/or after your plugin.

Comment: Yes its ok, what i mean is cant I put the output of my plugin inside that content instead of inserting it as a plugin from the backend? Will say I have a Table with 5 columns drawn in FE and need to call my extension in 2 cells of that table. Like calling inside {myPlugingName} or markesr ###myPluging### or some thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

You must be coming from Joomla!, right? If so, I think you're expecting some behaviour that's not implemented at all in TYPO3. In Joomla, you can (could?) insert a module, which is the equivalent of a TYPO3 plugin, anywhere in the content. Like here {mos_whatever}, and then {mos_whatever} would be parsed.

This is not how TYPO3 is thought to work. Plugins are inserted as content elements between other content elements. Or via TypoScript.

That said, there's always a way, maybe using or basing on the extension [ja_replacer](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/ja_replacer), which replaces patterns in the content, which is recommended for loading resources from another domain (to make YSlow happy).

But don't do it. I'm sure there's another, more safe and user friendly solution to your challenge in TYPO3.